# Want to add a startup notification Droid app

Tags: android, eclipse

I am looking to add a Notification when the app is started. That will ask the user if they have a WiFi or unlimited connection. If they pick yes then they can go into the app, if no then the app closes with a message 'Try again later...'

Comment: What is the reasoning behind asking the user on startup? You can determine if the user is on Wifi. If not have an option where the user can state they are on an unlimited connection. See CSipSimple - it's a VOIP application that does exactly this.

Comment: do you have link to CSipSimple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out if wifi is available, you don't need to ask the user, you can ask the OS to give you that information using this method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getTypeName%28%29

If you wish, you can also check if there is a connection using isConnected() and if you want to test if the connection is working, you could make a network call to confirm.

If you want to have the user confirm (I don't think you need to) then create an activity that runs when the app starts, it asks them to confirm, and then depending on their selection either starts the app's main activity, or shows a message and exits.

I don't know the details of your app, but if it were me I would probably:
 - Automate the network detection
 - If there's no network, run the app as usual, but just grey out and disable the main UI, and show a message like "Please connect to a Wifi network".
 - Consider including a user interface within the app that the user can use to turn on wifi.

I think that's much tidier than just exiting the app, as that means if they get the "no wifi" warning the app assists them by providing an option to enable it.

Comment: The details are this of app. When app starts want to notify user that a wifi or unlimited data connection is required, because of LIVE Video audio and chat feeds. If they do not have either have app exit. I will try what you are suggesting, and get back to you..

Comment: Are there any examples out there?

Comment: What you said is exactly what I want to do. Marakana close but no quit. I do appreciate all your help